# Change Background Image in Itext to watermark or alter opacity c# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to make my background image in iText transparent

here is my code for the image:

```
    string root = Server.MapPath("~");
    string parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(root);
    string grandParent = Path.GetDirectoryName(parent);
    string imageFilePath = parent + "/Images/logo.png";
    iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
    jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 800);
    jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
    jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 250);
    jpg.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(500);
    jpg.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(500);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [BackgroundTransparant](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/BackgroundTransparent) example. It is a variation on the [BackgroundImage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/BackgroundImage) example.

In your code, you're adding the `Image` to the `Document` instance. That's OK, but if you want to make such an image transparent, you need to introduce a soft mask. That's not difficult, but there's an easier way to make your background transparent: add the image to the direct content, and introduce a `PdfGState` defining the opacity:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
canvas.SaveState();
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.setFillOpacity(0.6f);
canvas.setGState(state);
canvas.addImage(image);
canvas.restoreState();
```

Compare [background_image.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/background_image.pdf) with [background_transparent.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/background_transparent.pdf) to see the difference.

My example is written in Java, but it's very easy to port this to C#:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContentUnder;
Image image = Image.GetInstance(IMAGE);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
canvas.SaveState();
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.FillOpacity = 0.6f;
canvas.SetGState(state);
canvas.AddImage(image);
canvas.RestoreState();
```