# How to make only the white part of a PDF stamp transparent?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfstamper

Using `iTextSharp`, I want to put a stamp on a PDF and make it transparent.  The stamp has colored text on it (various colors) that becomes difficult to read when the entire image is transparent, so I don't want to make the colored text transparent - only the white background in the stamp's rectangle.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243736/619177), I tried the following code:

```
public void addImage(PdfDictionary oldAnnot, string imagePath, 
                         int pageNumber,iTextSharp.text.Rectangle someRectangle) {
    Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
    PdfAnnotation pdfStamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(pdfStamper.Writer, someRectangle, null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    PdfAppearance app = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber).CreateAppearance(image.Width, image.Height);
    app.SaveState();
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.FillOpacity = 0.1f;
    app.SetGState(state);
    app.AddImage(image);
    app.RestoreState();
    pdfStamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
    pdfStamp.SetPage();
    pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(pdfStamp, pageNumber);
}
```

However, this makes the colored parts of the image translucent.  How can I make only the blank background of the image transparent and leave the colored parts opaque?

Thanks.

Comment: you're talking in circles here.. you want to put a stamp on a pdf and make it transparent, but don't want to make the color text transparent.. so you are not looking to make the stamp transparent.. why have you not just edited the image that exists at imagePath?

Comment: otherwise, the point of interest is going to be `Stream inputImageStream`..  you'll instead want to load the file into a GraphicContext, modify it accordingly, and provide a stream of the result to `GetInstance'.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, in some cases we want the image from imagePath to be opaque (for example, when stamping it on a dark gray background) and in other cases we want it to be transparent.  In this case I'm trying to replace a transparent stamp that was applied by Foxit in a way that makes it unreadable in Adobe.  You're saying that I can't use a white stamp and have to start out with a transparent stamp?

Comment: I'm saying `addImage` is not a method that should be responsible for editing your image.

Comment: first, you should overload this method, replacing `string imagePath` in the signature with `Stream inputImageStream` and remove the declaration and assignment of `inputImageStream` in that overload method. for, you will be modifying the image before calling this `addImage` method.

Comment: at this point, this question isn't even concerned with iTestSharp, now it's just concerned with reading an image from file, and editing that image in memory (affecting the alpha channel on each pixel that is white), and result in a System.IO.Stream (with `Position = 0`) of the edited image.

Comment: which begs the question, what image format are these images?.. hopefully one that has an alpha channel

Comment: actually. there is an alternative.. and that is to use blend modes.. on the `PdfGState` via setBlendMode [PdfGState](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfGState.html)

Comment: @BrettCaswell the image at `imagePath` is a JPEG.  I'm reading now that JPEG doesn't support transparency, is that correct?

Comment: that's correct, if you go with loading and modifying the image route, you'll end up having to convert the image to another image format

Comment: How about using a blend mode like **Darken** or **Multiply**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially are asking for the *Colour Key Masking* PDF feature. Unfortunately

> When colour key masking is specified, the use of a **DCTDecode** or lossy **JPXDecode** filter for the stream can produce unexpected results.

*(section 8.9.6.4 – Colour Key Masking – ISO 32000-1)*

As you have a JPEG and JPEGs usually are embedded in PDFs using the **DCTDecode** filter, Colour Key Masking might not work as desired.

---

Instead of working with transparency you might want to try using a different blend mode, e.g. **Darken** or **Multiply**.

> **Multiply** B(c<sub>b</sub>, c<sub>s</sub>) = c<sub>b</sub> * c<sub>s</sub>
>
> NOTE 1 Multiplies the backdrop and source colour values.
>
> NOTE 2 The result colour is always at least as dark as either of the two constituent colours. Multiplying any colour with black produces black; multiplying with white leaves the original colour unchanged. Painting successive overlapping objects with a colour other than black or white produces progressively darker colours.
>
> **Darken** B(c<sub>b</sub>, c<sub>s</sub>) = min(c<sub>b</sub>, c<sub>s</sub>)
>
> NOTE 6 Selects the darker of the backdrop and source colours.
>
> NOTE 7 The backdrop is replaced with the source where the source is darker; otherwise, it is left unchanged.

*(Table 136 – Standard separable blend modes – ISO 32000-1)*

To select a blend mode, you can use a `PdfGState` like you already do but instead of setting the opacity

```
state.FillOpacity = 0.1f;
```

you set the blend mode

```
state.BlendMode = PdfGState.BM_MULTIPLY;
```

or

```
state.BlendMode = PdfGState.BM_DARKEN;
```

Comment: **Darken** seems to provide the transparency that I'm looking for.  Thanks.